# Achieving a polynomial that maps from $GF(p^q)$ to {0,1} with the same probability

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I am using an arithmetic circuit, which can compute polynomials over the field $GF(p^q)$.

I need a polynomial that maps any element from the field to an element from $\{0,1\}$, I need that the range will distribute uniformly in $\{0,1\}$, i.e. that the number of elements that are mapped to $0$ is equal to the number of elements that are mapped to $1$.

(Remember that an arithmetic circuit composed of $+$ and $\times$ gates.

Comment: Literally equal? $p^q$ is odd for $p\ne 2$.

Comment: Yes, literally equal. I don't know how to test whether a number is odd or even using an arithmetic circuit.

Comment: ???? You *know* that $p^q$ is even only for $p=2$.

Comment: You just told me that in the first comment. But I don't see how I can use this fact for the mapping that I'm seeking for...

Comment: You *can't* do what you want except for $p=2$.